# Not Ajax-related controls in AjaxControlToolkit?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Why AjaxControlToolkit contains controls like [DropShadow](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/DropShadow/DropShadow.aspx) that are not related to Ajax really? Such controls just make use of JavaScript and does not send or receive any data to/from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are correct: they contain javascript, not "real" AJAX.

But "AJAX" is now often used to mean "anything that uses javascript/dhtml to make a page more responsive and avoid postbacks", not just "Asynchronous Javascript And Xml" (the original definition).